# How to make a 10x10 rectangle of "#" characters?

Tags: javascript

I am working with jquery and upon the HTML document completing loading, I need to display a 10x10 rectangle of "#" characters in my div tag whose ID is "artArea". I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help would be wonderful!

Here is my current progress: I am not sure if my `function (retangle)` is completely wrong or if I am calling the function incorrectly. https://jsfiddle.net/7u1ao2d9/

Comment: hit f12 you will see JS errors that you need to figure out (hint your for loop isn't formatted correctly) start there

Comment: funny how people resort to jquery where they don't know how to use double loop yet.. do you want to be a real programmer or a web designer?

Comment: Funny how i'm a beginner and in my first javascript class and there are people like @davidhaim who are so incredibly rude. I am sure you weren't born a javascript genius.

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't care about DOM manipulations and design before you know how code works. it is almost obsurd that you try to present something inside a div before you know how to use loops! there is something clearly wrong in the silibus you are learning from!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code. For one, it's not a great idea to stick the script tag that draws your "#" rectangle in the div where you want the rectangle to go. It is a much better practice to put the script tags with the rest of your script tags at the bottom of the document. In this case, since you're using jQuery, make sure you put the rectangle drawing script tag BELOW the script tag that loads the jQuery library.

Now if your script tag is in the right place, the following should work for you:

```
<script>
    function drawRect(){
        var rect = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i +=1){
            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j += 1){
                rect += "#"
            }
            rect += "\n"
        }

        return rect;
    }

    document.getElementById("artArea").innerHTML = drawRect();
</script>
```

All the above function is doing is using nested for-loops to build up a string of text. For every one time the outer loop runs, the inner loop will run ten times, so the function uses the inner loop to add 10 "#"s to the string, then the outer loop adds one "\n" to the end of the the 10 "#"s. The "\n" is called a newline character and causes a line-break in the text. To make sure this line-break renders in your html, add the following code to your css file:

```
#artArea {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Once the nested loops finish running, we have a string that contains a 10x10 grid of "#"s. Now all that remains is to select the HTML element we want to display the grid and insert that string into it. That's what the `document.querySelector("#artArea").innerHTML = drawRect();` line does.

It's not super-obvious from your question, but looking at your code, it appears that you want this rectangle function to be able to draw different grids composed of different characters, depending on user input. If that's the case, then you would want to grab the input and pass it in as an argument to your function, like so:

```
var rows= parseInt($("#numRows").val(), 10);
var cols= parseInt($("#numCols").val(), 10);
var char= ("#drawChar").val();
function drawRect(rows,cols,char){
            var rect = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i +=1){
                for (var j = 0; j < cols; j += 1){
                    rect += char;
                }
                rect += "\n"
            }

            return rect;
        }

drawRect(rows,cols,char);
```

Just be aware that writing the function this way opens the door to possible errors and even security lapses depending upon user input. For example, if the user doesn't put a number into the row or col fields, that will break the code. So if you go this route you need to do more error-checking, character escaping, etc.

Comment: Just a couple of things: `document.querySelector("#artArea")` really? `document.getElementById("artArea")` if you please. Additionally, `parseInt`'s second argument is NOT optional and should be specified as `parseInt($("#numRows"),10)`. The only real check needed is `ifNaN()` to ensure that it is indeed a number, and perhaps restrict `char` to one character with `$("#drawChar").val().charAt(0);` (silently discards all characters after the first)

Comment: Point taken on parseInt, but what's the problem with `querySelector`? It's supported in all modern browsers and the fact that it takes css selectors is a nice perk.

Comment: You're using a very broad tool for something when you already have the specific tool needed. Given a set of tools, you should try to use the one best suited to the job, and in this case that is `getElementById`. Bonus points because it's been around since the dawn of time, sort of, whereas `querySelector` is a much newer thing.

Comment: Ok makes sense. And I guess `getElementById` is slightly more efficient as well. Since the guy's using jQuery anyway, should've just said `$(#artArea)` and skirted the whole issue. Oh, well. Edited original to reflect proposed changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the width of the given `#` character. Here is the code used to find the dimensions of the `#` character and calculate the dimensions for the container. Be sure that the target div and the character calculating divs both have the same line height and font size. Be sure to put the `#charWidth` div out of sight.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#charWidth').html('#');
  var charWidth = $('#charWidth').width();
  var charHeight = $('#charWidth').height();
  var target = document.getElementById('target');
  target.style.width = 10 * charWidth + 'px';
  target.style.height = 10 * charHeight + 'px';
  console.log(10 * charWidth);
  console.log(10 * charHeight);
  for (var i = 0; i != 100; i++) {
    if ((i % 10) == 0) target.innerHTML += '<br>';
    target.innerText += '#';
  }
});
```

```css
#charWidth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5000000000000vh;
  opacity: 0;
  display: table;
  /*be sure that it has the same line height and font size as your target div*/
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
#target {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="charWidth"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Count up to 100 while inserting a line break every 10 counts. Use the function to generate the output and use it on any element you want.

```
function rectangle(){
        var r = "";

        //Go about 10x10=100 counts
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
            if (i % 10 === 0)       //Insert line break every 10 counts
               r += "\n"
            else
               r += "#";           
        }

        return r;
    }

$('#artArea').val() = rectangle();
```

Also consider this typical script pattern

```
<html>
   <head>

      <script>
         $(document).ready(...)
      </script> 

   </head>

   <body>
      ...
   </body> 
</html>
```

You can use [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to debug your script.

Answer (score 0):

This version creates a table made up of Rows x Cols cells, places a # (or whatever you set Char to) inside each cell, and leaves you with something you can modify by using id = r(row number)c(col number).
I placed this block inside the head of the document.

As others have suggested, there should be some kind of input validation to ensure people do not place an array of javascript code pieces or similar.

Style the table and cells to make your output do what you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rectangle()
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    var Rows = parseInt($("input#numRows").val(), 10);
    var Cols = parseInt($("input#numCols").val(), 10);
    var Char = $("input#drawChar").val());

    var artArea = document.getElementById("artArea")

    if (document.getElementById("artTable"))
    {
        //  assuming we made it
        artArea.removeChild(document.getElementById("artTable"))
    }

    var my_table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    my_table.id = "artTable"
    artArea.appendChild(my_table);

    for (var i=0; i < Rows; i++)
    {
        var this_row = document.createElement("TR")
        this_row.id = "r" + i;
        for ( var j=0; j < Cols; j++)
        {
                var this_cell = document.createElement("TD");
                this_cell.id = this_row.id + "c" + j;
                var my_text = document.createTextNode(Char);
                this_cell.appendChild(my_text);
                this_row.appendChild(this_cell);
        }
        my_table.appendChild(this_row);
    }
}

$( document ).ready(function() { rectangle(); });
</script>
```

Tried it on jsfiddle, but have not made a document.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner, excluding the docready:

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#artArea').html("#".repeat(10).concat("\n").repeat(10))
);
```

You'll want to, like @btwebste mentioned, use a `white-space` declaration to ensure that the newlines are rendered.

```
#artArea {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rgjy50e5/